# Thinking Sphinx delayed delta indexing - index not updated on record deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, thinking-sphinx

I'm having trouble using delayed deltas with thinking_sphinx. This is the model:

```
Event
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
  ...
  define_index do
    indexes name
    indexes users(:id), :as => :user_id
    set_property :delta => :delayed
  ...

Subscription
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user

User
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :events, :through => :subscriptions
```

When a user adds/removes a subscription I set the delta flag to all the corresponding events through the subscription model callbacks like this:

```
after_save :set_events_delta_flag
after_destroy :set_events_delta_flag

def set_events_delta_flag
  Event.define_indexes
  sql = "UPDATE events SET delta = true FROM subscriptions"
  sql << " WHERE events.id = subscriptions.event_id AND (subscriptions.id = #{self.id})"
  Event.connection.update(sql)
  Event.index_delta
end
```

It works ok when a user adds a subscription: the callback runs and then a ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DeltaJob job runs and updates the index. However when a user removes a subscription the callback and the DeltaJob run, but it seems that the index does not get updated:

If I do something like:

```
Event.search("". :with => {:user_id => XX}).search_count
```

before and after remove a subscription, the count does not change (it changes before and after **adding** a subscription)

is this an expected behavior? What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: It seems that Sphinx storig two copies of the same document (one in the core index and one in the delta index) is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With upgrade to Sphinx 2.0.3, this problem of having 2 indices will go away. the indices will be merged into single. You can try upgrading it.